# LMS1xx driver connecting to scanner but not actually scanning?

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am using a SICK LMS151 laser scanner that I am trying to set up with ROS.  I downloaded this driver:

https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/LMS1xx

initially just with sudo apt-get, but that didn't download all the correct files, so I ended up creating my own LMS1xx directory, and copying all the text from the package.xml, CMakeLists, nodes, launch files, etc. directly into the files on my computer.  THen I compiled it with catkin_make (no errors), and ran it with my laser scanner plugged in (with the correct ip address).  Everything seemed to be going correctly; it said it connected to the laser at the correct ip address, but then it proceeded to not do anything else.  I thought this driver was supposed to run laser scans and print the data, so I checked the LMS1xx_node file, and I saw that indeed, after printing that ROS has connected to the laser, the node is supposed to do other things ti (that look to me like performing scans, but I' not sure).

In between the command to print "connected to laser" and the scan loop however, I see the following code:

do //wait for ready status
{
stat = laser.queryStatus();
ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
}

while (stat != read_for_measurement);

So apparently for some reason the laser is not returning a ready status to the node, and thus the scans are not beginning.  Anyone know why this could be?  I am running ROS hydro on ubuntu 12.04 on virtualbox on windows 7 (maybe this is the problem, if the virtual machine is somehow messing up the laser/computer communication).

Thanks,

Randy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182904/lms1xx-driver-connecting-to-scanner-but-not-actually-scanning?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-07-14**:
Hey, sorry for taking so long to get back to you, I was switching to a dual boot and then solving the new problems that came along.  However, I am now successfully running ubuntu 12.04 directly and tried your suggestion.

Turns out you were right; although the node isn't announcing that it's publishing anything, it is.  Scan was listed on rostopic list, and subscribing to it produced a real looking data stream (not all 0's).

Thanks a lot!  Now I'm gonna see if I can get this data to display in rviz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Once you run the node, what is the output of "rostopic list" ? By default the readings of the laser should appear no the topic /scan.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0